# Unable to create a file on ubuntu using php

Tags: php

I am trying to create a simple text file on my server using PHP.

I have given `777` permission to the folder still I am unable to create the file it gives following error:

```
Warning: fopen(demo.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/code/fcreate.php on line 6 unable to create
```

The PHP code is as follows:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

fopen('demo.txt','r') or die('unable to create');

?>
```

Comment: From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/function.fopen.php) ~ *mode 'r' - Open for reading only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file.*

Comment: fopen should create the file if it does not exists . But the file is not being created when i see in the folder

Comment: There are several modes that will attempt to create the file if it does not exist and you can see them all on the `fopen` manual page. Hint ~ *r* is **not** one of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to read a file because of that flag you're using `r` (read).

The flag `r` stands for:

> **'r'** Open for reading only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file.

You can use `a+` read/write. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

```
$handle = fopen('demo.txt','a+') or die('unable to create');
```

If you want more clarity. Kindly visit the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for more details. (Check out the **modes** part).

Comment: fopen('demo.txt','w') or die('unable to create'); instead of demo.txt i need to give full path '/var/www/demo.txt' this solved my error